# How to add link Sitemap in head in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, sitemap, prestashop-1.5

In PrestShop, I have 5 languages, so I have also 5 sitemaps like this:

```
1_de_0_sitemap.xml
1_en_0_sitemap.xml
1_lv_0_sitemap.xml,
etc.
```

How I can add link for sitemap to `<head>` for current front-end language?

It is PrestaShop 1.5.

The right way is doing it in .tpl or in some Controller?

Comment: Why do you want to add it to the header? Sitemaps are not meant to be linked int each request (it doesn't make sense). Instead you should have a  sitemap index which lists all your sitemaps for specific languages. `gsitemap` module does exactly that. Also you can link your sitemaps in Google Search Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in header.tpl, but I recommend you that used hookHeader insted. Something like this:

```
public function hookHeader($params)
{
    $sitemap_file = '1_' . $this->context->language->iso_code . '_0_sitemap.xml';
    //could work with echo too
    return 'your link here' . $sitemap_file;
}
```

Good luck